# Using Gdata to get stats about a video

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, youtube-api

I am populating a table with a result from queries of YouTube videos by using the **Google API**. I see there is a header file in the api called `GDataYouTubeStatistics.h` but I don't necessarily know how to go about accessing the data.

```
DataEntryBase *entry = [[feed entries] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSString *title = [[entry title] stringValue];
NSArray *thumbnails = [[(GDataEntryYouTubeVideo *)entry mediaGroup] mediaThumbnails];
```

That is how I go about getting the thumbnails and the titles but I need view counts and other stat properties.

Thanks any help would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well after some work...this is how you solve it.

```
 //This video is from the feed.
 GDataEntryYouTubeVideo * video;

GDataYouTubeRating * rating = [video rating];

GDataYouTubeStatistics * stats = [video statistics];

NSNumber * likes = [rating numberOfLikes];    
NSNumber * dislikes = [rating numberOfDislikes];

 NSNumber * views2 = [stats viewCount];
```